# if ( ) < /dev/null

Tags: bash, unix

I can't wrap my head around this. Why would `/dev/null` be used as input to an `if` statement? What is the use of `< /dev/null` in the following?

```
if ( $PROG --version ) < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        $PROG
else
        echo "failed"
        exit 1
fi
```

I (think) I understand that `> /dev/null 2>&1` is just used to suppress any output from both `stdout` and `stderr`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If `$PROG` is a program that expects input from `stdin`, your script might stall forever waiting for you to type something in.  The use of `< /dev/null` is to provide an empty input to such a program.   You're right about  the `>` and `2>&1`.

This snippet of script is checking to see if `$PROG --version` exits with a 0 status (success), and then runs that program without any flags.  If `$PROG --version` fails, the script echoes "failed" and exits.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not sure how useful this is if I know what `$PROG` is and I know that `PROG --version` isn't waiting for input. For example, `PROG=autoconf` is one where I saw this. And I know that `autoconf --version` is not waiting for input. Is it still useful in this case?

Comment: @Carl Norum, could the `if ( '$PROG --version' ) ` (with angle brackets) be used here to execute the command and thus no need for `< /dev/null` ?

Comment: @fduff: (a) There are no angle brackets in your comment. (b) You have single quotes which will cause the shell to treat `'$PROG --version'` as a string literal, not as a command to be executed, which will be an error unless you happen to have a command whose name is literally `'$PROG --version'`. Can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: I meant that: "`$PROG --version`" to execute the command. The "`" is used in SO for `code` formatting.

Answer (score 15):

I think you're wondering why the redirection is outside the parentheses.

In this line:

```
if ( $PROG --version ) < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1; then
```

the parentheses aren't part of the syntax of the `if` statement; they just specify command grouping.  (It took me a moment to remember that myself; in csh/tcsh, parentheses *are* part of the syntax of an `if` statement.)

For example, this:

```
( echo one ; echo two ) | tr a-z A-Z
```

will produce this output:

```
ONE
TWO
```

In this case, since `$PROG --version` is a single command, the parentheses are unnecessary (unless `$PROG` expands to more than one command, but that's unlikely).

So the redirection doesn't apply to the `if` statement; it applies to `$PROG --version`.  The purpose is to provide no input (as if reading from an empty file) to `$PROG`, and to discard anything it writes to stdout or stderr.  If `$PROG` is a command that reads from stdin, even when invoked with `--version`, then without the input redirection it could hang waiting for keyboard input.

The script assumes that it's safe to invoke `$PROG` (whatever it may be) only if `$PROG --version` doesn't produce an error.

Note that you *can* apply redirection to an if statement:

```
if test_command ; then
    something
else
    something_else
fi < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This redirects input and output for `test_command`, `something`, *and* `something_else`.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer! I was indeed confused regarding the parentheses. Thanks for breaking it down for me and for giving examples. Great explanation.